# How do you change the data such as the mph/hr per train, starting time, total distance of the problem so that trains B and C travel the same distance?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you change the data such as the mph/hr per train, starting time, total distance of the problem so that trains B and C travel the same distance?

Train A traveling at 60 m/hr leaves New York for Dallas at 6 P.M. Train B traveling at 90 m/hr also leaves New York for Dallas at 9 P.M. Train C leaves Dallas for New York at 9 P.M. If all three trains meet at the same time between New York and Dallas, what is the speed of Train C if the distance between Dallas and New York is 1260 miles?

Someone told me this,

> Set the times and speeds for A and B and determine the distance at which they meet.

> This is simply

> Meeting Distance = SpeedA * (TimeX - TimeA) = SpeedB * (TimeX - TimeB) = SpeedC * (TimeX - TimeB)

> Then the total distance is just double this.

Don't you need one more equation?

Comment: The difficulty with this problem is that (in my opinion) the wording of the offered solution is badly mangled.  Let the speeds of A,B,C be $~S_a, S_b, S_c~$ respectively.  Then, the time needed for B to overtake A is $$T = \frac{180}{S_b - S_a},$$ since A has a $~180~$ mile head start.  Then, the distance that B has traveled during this time is $$D_1 = S_b \times T.$$  So, the distance that C will travel is $$D_2 = 1260 - D_1.$$  Then, C's speed may be computed as $$\frac{D_2}{T}.$$

Comment: $D_2/T=S_b \implies D_1=630$, not enough equations to solve?

Answer (score 2):

- A travels $60*3 = 180$ mi between 6pm and 9pm
- B needs $\frac{Distance\; apart}{Relative\; Vel} = \frac{180}{90-60} = 6$ hrs to catch up ($3$ am)
- B has travelled $6*90 =540$ miles to catch up
- Meeting point dist. from Dallas $= 1260-540 = 720$ mi
- Train from Dallas starting at $9$pm and meeting at $3$ am needs to travel at $\frac{720}6 = 120$ mph

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution quoted in the question is correct up to here:

> Meeting Distance = SpeedA * (TimeX - TimeA) = SpeedB * (TimeX - TimeB)

This is a solvable problem, because you have two equations and only two unknowns. In fact, if you just take the second equation,

> SpeedA * (TimeX - TimeA) = SpeedB * (TimeX - TimeB)

you have only one unknown, TimeX, and can solve for it. Then plug back into the original equations to find Meeting Distance.

This part is nonsense:

> SpeedB * (TimeX - TimeB) = SpeedC * (TimeX - TimeB)

The problem statement said C was traveling from a different starting point
and there is no guarantee that it traveled the same distance as B.
In fact, as you can see from the correct solution another answer,
train C travels farther than train B and is therefore faster.

For the same reason, the following also is nonsense:

> Then the total distance is just double this.

You technically do need a few more equations to get the final answer,
but you can construct them one at a time.
At no point in this problem do you need to solve two or more equations simultaneously.

---

There are, of course, various ways to modify the problem so that trains B and C cover the same distance. With the given starting conditions for trains A and B, train B has traveled $540$ miles at the instant it catches up to train A. To make train C travel the same distance as train B, we could simply make it travel $540$ miles, which we can do by supposing that the distance from New York to Dallas is $1080$ miles. (It isn't, but since the as-the-crow-flies distance between New York and Dallas is greater than $1260$ miles, the distance in the problem is already fictional.)

In order to make the total distance $1260$ miles but have B and C travel equal distances, they must both travel $630$ miles. You can achieve this by making it take $7$ hours for train B (traveling at $90$ mph) to catch up with train A. You could have train $A$ leave earlier, at $5{:}30$ PM, so that its head start is $210$ miles rather than $180$ miles.
Alternatively, you could have train $A$ travel at $63$ mph, so that it covers the distance in $10$ hours that train $B$ covers in $7$ hours.
Or you could change speeds and starting times together.

Note that if you preserve the fact that trains B and C start at the same time and you make the meeting point be exactly half way between the two starting points, you guarantee that trains B and C travel at the same speed.
Since the speed of train B is given, just copy the number.
No need for algebra or even any information about train A.

And this last part should be a clue that even if you tweak the problem so that trains B and C travel an equal distance, the proposed "solution method" is **still wrong**. By tweaking the problem you will merely have set up a problem for which this **wrong method** just happens (by sheer coincidence) to give the same numeric result as a correct method does.